# In Windows 10, is it possible to have multiple Taskbar groups of the same "kind" (but different "id"s)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, cmd.exe

I run Windows 10. On the Tasbar, there's a bunch of icons. One of these icons is cmd.exe.
At any given moment, I have a number of cmd.exe-based programs (PHP CLI scripts) running.
These windows all group themselves into the cmd.exe icon, so that I can click it and get a menu of all running PHP CLI scripts.

With increasing numbers of scripts running, especially ones that open 10-25 "children processes", this has become inconvenient and messy. I'd like to be able to somehow assign an "id" of some kind so that windows with the same id group together in their own cmd.exe Taskbar "group". I don't care if the icon is the same, as long as they don't all put themselves in the same group.

This feels like it is probably possible somehow, but I haven't figured out how.

I have looked at the manual for "cmd.exe /?" and "start /?", but they don't list any such "id flag" for me to use. As so often is the case, my assumption about how they solved a problem is false. It may not even be possible at all...

Answer (score 0):

The only "id flag" that I know of is the name of the executable, `cmd.exe` in this case.

If you want to group the icons separately, you need another `cmd.exe`.

As Administrator, you may copy `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` to the same folder as,
say, `cmd2.exe`, then use `cmd2.exe` instead of `cmd.exe`.